# How to organise photos of people along with their biography and contact information?

Tags: photos, contacts

I know ~300 people, and I have ~500 photos. Some photos have one person in each of the photos, some photos have many people in each of the photos. For not forgetting people, I write down their names, ages, occupations, their relations to me, emotional personalities, addresses, phone numbers, quotes of words they ever said, things they ever did, etcetera. I want to inspect the collection of photos of this person and the biography of this person in some unionised place for one person.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

A MediaWiki wiki would work very well for this. Have a page for each person along with their photo.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is not enough clear, I would propose you to create a folder structure with the name of every person and writing in a text file all the needed information for each one of them.

Comment: This would not work because a photo with multiple people would have to be copied into several folders, which creates unnecessary disk space.